Polars: set missing value from another row
The following data frame represents basic flatten tree structure, as shown below, where pairs (id, sub-id) and (sub-id, key) are always unique and key always represents the same thing under the same id
id1
└─┬─ sub-id 
│ │   └─── key1
│ │        └─── value
│ └─ sub-id2 
│     └─── key1
│          └─── None
id2
└─── sub-id3 
      └─── key2
           └─── value

with graphical representation out of the way, below is the definition as polars.DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "sub-id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
        "key": ["key_1_1", "key_1_2", "key_2_1", "key_2_1", "key_2_2", "key_3"],
        "value": ["value1 1", "value 1 2", None, "value 2 1", "value 2 2", "value 3"],
    }
)

The same data frame in table representation:
shape: (6, 4)

┌────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ ID │ sub-id │ key     │ value     │
╞════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1  │ 1      │ key_1_1 │ value 1   │
│ 1  │ 1      │ key_1_2 │ value 2   │
│ 2  │ 2      │ key_2_1 │ value 2 1 │
│ 2  │ 3      │ key_2_1 │ None      │
│ 2  │ 3      │ key_2_2 │ value 2 2 │
│ 3  │ 4      │ key_3   │ value 3   │
└────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

How would I to fill gaps like shown below using polars. total size of data is about 100k rows.
shape: (6, 4)

┌────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ ID │ sub-id │ key     │ value     │
╞════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1  │ 1      │ key_1_1 │ value 1   │
│ 1  │ 1      │ key_1_2 │ value 2   │
│ 2  │ 2      │ key_2_1 │ value 2 1 │
│ 2  │ 3      │ key_2_1 │ value 2 1 │
│ 2  │ 3      │ key_2_2 │ value 2 2 │
│ 3  │ 4      │ key_3   │ value 3   │
└────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────┘


The dataframe code and the "table representation" are 2 different dataframes. Can you fix the example to clarify what the exact goal is?

There is pl.Expr.fill_null to fill missing values.
As fill value, we use the first non-null value with the same id and key. As we assume that all values for the same id and key are the same, taking the first value is reasonable. It can be constructed as follows:

pl.Expr.filter and  pl.Expr.is_not_null to filter for non-null values,
pl.Expr.first to select the first such value,
the window function pl.Expr.over to evaluate the expression separately for each id and key pair.

df.with_columns(
    pl.col("value").fill_null(
        pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null()).first().over("id", "key")
    )
)

shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ id  ┆ sub-id ┆ key     ┆ value     │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64    ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞═════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1      ┆ key_1_1 ┆ value 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 1      ┆ key_1_2 ┆ value 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 2      ┆ key_2_1 ┆ value 2 1 │
│ 2   ┆ 3      ┆ key_2_1 ┆ value 2 1 │
│ 2   ┆ 3      ┆ key_2_2 ┆ value 2 2 │
│ 3   ┆ 4      ┆ key_3   ┆ value 3   │
└─────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

Note. I needed to adapt your code slightly to match the example you described in the text.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
    "sub-id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
    "key": ["key_1_1", "key_1_2", "key_2_1", "key_2_1", "key_2_2", "key_3"],
    "value": ["value 1", "value 2", None, "value 2 1", "value 2 2", "value 3"],
})


Thank you, it works perfectly in my case. I still have missing values, but I think this is an unrecoverable loss of data.

What would help you achieve this is by performing a forward fill operation based on both id and key it makes sure  missing values within the same id and key groups are filled with the most recent non-null value
Using with_columns  made it possible to use forward_fill operation
To clarify further:

pl.col("value"): This selects the value column from the DataFrame.
forward_fill(): This method fills any None values with the last known non-null value within the specified context.

over(["id", "key"]): This would ensures that the fill-operation respects the grouping by both id and key.
In other words, the fill operation only happens within each id and key group, so values from different groups don’t interfere with each other.


I have provided a code snippet to guide you...
import polars as pl

# Define the DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "sub-id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
        "key": ["key_1_1", "key_1_2", "key_2_1", "key_2_1", "key_2_2", "key_3"],
        "value": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 2 1", None, "value 2 2", "value 3"],
    }
)

# Perform the fill operation
filled_df = df.with_columns(pl.col("value").forward_fill().over(["ID", "key"]))

# Display the result
print(filled_df)

Results:
shape: (6, 4)
┌─────┬────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ ID  ┆ sub-id ┆ key     ┆ value     │
│ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---     ┆ ---       │
│ i64 ┆ i64    ┆ str     ┆ str       │
╞═════╪════════╪═════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1   ┆ 1      ┆ key_1_1 ┆ value 1   │
│ 1   ┆ 1      ┆ key_1_2 ┆ value 2   │
│ 2   ┆ 2      ┆ key_2_1 ┆ value 2 1 │
│ 2   ┆ 3      ┆ key_2_1 ┆ value 2 1 │
│ 2   ┆ 3      ┆ key_2_2 ┆ value 2 2 │
│ 3   ┆ 4      ┆ key_3   ┆ value 3   │
└─────┴────────┴─────────┴───────────┘

Alternatively
You can use join to achieve this also by joining the non-null df with the original df you have before.
Below is a code snippet
import polars as pl

# Define the DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3],
        "sub-id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4],
        "key": ["key_1_1", "key_1_2", "key_2_1", "key_2_1", "key_2_2", "key_3"],
        "value": ["value 1", "value 2", "value 2 1", None, "value 2 2", "value 3"],
    }
)

# Separate the non-null values
non_null_df = df.filter(pl.col("value").is_not_null())

# Join the original DataFrame with the non-null DataFrame
new_table_joined_df = df.join(non_null_df, on=["ID", "key"], how="left", suffix="_filled")

# Fill the original `value` column with the joined `value_filled` column
filled_df = new_table_joined_df.with_columns(pl.col("value").fill_null(pl.col("value_filled"))).select(df.columns)

# Display the result
print(filled_df)

